# Obtain all records longer than 25 characters (LENGTH(hcp.phone_number) > 25)

Tags: sql

Im trying without success to obtain all records from my query based on this condition:

```
(LENGTH(hcp.phone_number) > 25)
```

Actually i am using this condition:

```
CASE WHEN LENGTH(hcp.phone_number) > 25 then null else hcp.phone_number END
```

But it just shows me NULL when the **hcp.phone_number** field is greater than 25, for a single account number.

My query works properly but i want to modify it in order to obtain **ALL** the account numbers that match this condition:

```
LENGTH(hcp.phone_number) > 25
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT
    hp.party_name                              
  , hca.account_number
  , hca.cust_account_id                        
 -- , hcsu.LOCATION customer_site_name
  , hcas.cust_acct_site_id                     
  , hcp.phone_number
  , hcp.email_address
  , CASE WHEN LENGTH(hcp.phone_number) > 25 then null else hcp.phone_number END
  , hl.address1
  , hl.address2
  , hl.address3
  , hl.address4
  , hl.city
  , hl.province
  , hl.postal_code
  , hcas.status  as hcas_status                               
  , DECODE( hcas.attribute5, 'PUP', 'Y', 'N' ) 
  , hca.status  as hca_status                             
FROM apps.hz_cust_accounts hca
INNER JOIN apps.hz_cust_acct_sites_all hcas ON hca.cust_account_id = hcas.cust_account_id
INNER JOIN apps.hz_party_sites hps ON hcas.party_site_id = hps.party_site_id
INNER JOIN apps.hz_locations hl ON hps.location_id = hl.location_id
INNER JOIN apps.hz_parties hp ON hps.party_id = hp.party_id
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            owner_table_id
          , max(case when contact_point_type = 'PHONE' then phone_number end) phone_number
          , max(case when contact_point_type = 'EMAIL' then email_address end) email_address
        FROM hz_contact_points
        WHERE status = 'A'
        AND primary_flag = 'Y'
        AND owner_table_name = 'HZ_PARTY_SITES'
        AND contact_point_type IN ('EMAIL','PHONE')
        GROUP BY 
            owner_table_id
    ) hcp ON hcas.party_site_id = hcp.owner_table_id 
WHERE hcas.status = 'A'
AND hps.status = 'A'
AND hca.status = 'A'
AND hca.account_number = ''
;
```

Can you help me with this?

Comment: Hint:  Add the condition to the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you for replying. Yeah, but for some reason it is not working :(

Comment: I dont know how to modify it in order to obtain ALL the account numbers that match that condition.. i am a little confused :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should change your selected column to this

```
, CASE WHEN LENGTH(hcp.phone_number) > 25 then hcp.phone_number END
```

And delete the condition `AND hca.account_number = ''`

If you want to filter out all the recored with LENGTH(hcp.phone_number) <= 25 in your result then add condition in `WHERE` clause: `AND LENGTH(hcp.phone_number) > 25`.

Comment: I dont know why but somebody downvoted my question..
Thank you for replying, dude, i tried to do that but it is not working.. it does not show me all the account numbers at all :(

Comment: @programming_amazing if you want to show all account numbers then delete this from your query: `AND hca.account_number = ''`

Comment: Dude, what do you mean by: "you should change your select column to this"? What would you change in my code?

Comment: Oh, sorry.. i feel pretty stupid now. My bad.
Thanks!